# Unable to send mail using parse.com and Mailgun in ionic application from mobile device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an application in ionic where I have build a ***contact us*** form, I have used **Mailgun** and **parse.com** to send mail from my application. When I send mail from my browser to test my IONIC application it worked perfectly, but when I tried to do it from my mobile then it's not working. I don't know the problem.  Below is my code to send mail from my IONIC application.

```
var spinner_android = '<ion-spinner icon="android" class="spinner-light"></ion-spinner>';
        $scope.contactUs = function (contactObj) {
            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: spinner_android
            });
            var parseAPPID = "<parseAPPID>";
            var parseJSID = "<parseJSID>";
            Parse.initialize(parseAPPID, parseJSID);
            Parse.Cloud.run('contactus', contactObj, {
                success: function (results) {
                    $scope.resultMessageSuccess = 'Message sent.';
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.resultMessageError = 'Error in sending message, please try again';
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: what platforms have you tested it on? android or ios or both?

Comment: I have tested it on Android

Comment: If it is on android the problem may be that android devices have a outdated and fragmented web view. I would highly recommend testing a build using the crosswalk engine. https://crosswalk-project.org/